# how to use verbose name in foreign key django admin?

Tags: django

how to use verbose_name in foreign key django admin??

```
class ParentsProfile(models.Model):
    Fathers_Firstname = models.CharField(verbose_name="Firstname", max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Fathers_Middle_Initial = models.CharField(verbose_name="Middle Initial", max_length=500,null=True,blank=True, help_text="Father")
    Fathers_Lastname = models.CharField(verbose_name="Lastname", max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Educational_AttainmentID_Father = models.ForeignKey(EducationalAttainment,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
```

I've already try to use **Educational_AttainmentID_Father = models.ForeignKey("EducationalAttainment",EducationalAttainment,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)** but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
Educational_AttainmentID_Father = models.ForeignKey(EducationalAttainment, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True, verbose_name="EducationalAttainment")
```

Comment: oh I see, it works now, I get the error because of the position of  verbose_name , thanks